# Consolidating data from columns to rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a spreadsheet:

```
Company 1 | ID1
Company 1 | ID2
Company 1 | ID3
Company 2 | ID4
Company 2 | ID5
Company 2 | ID6
Company 3 | ID7
Company 3 | ID8
Company 3 | ID9
```

I need to combine each company into one row, with all their IDs into columns to the right. There can be a different number of IDs per company.

The final result would look like:

```
Company 1 | ID1 | ID2 | ID3
Company 2 | ID4 | ID5 | ID6
Company 3 | ID7 | ID8 | ID9
```

How could I accomplish this? Preferably with VBA.

Comment: If you can add a Column for the Table，please try Power Query: http://chuantu.biz/t6/335/1530177159x-1404792307.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This single formula solution assumes that each company has the same number of rows:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `D2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down&right into the rest of the table:

```dart
=""&INDEX($A:$B,ROW($D$2)+3*INT(ROW()-ROW($D$2))+MAX(0,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D$2)-1),2-(COLUMN()=COLUMN($D$2)))
```

Note that this formula will work for any (identical) number of rows for each company, and will correctly adjust if rows or columns are added/removed.

However, the formula will break if the table it is in is copied/cut and pasted elsewhere. The `$D$2`s need to be changed to match the new table location's top-left data cell in order to make it work correctly again.

---

If there is a variable number of rows for each company, the single formula required is:

```dart
=IFERROR(IF(COLUMN()=COLUMN($D$2),""&INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(D1,$A:$A,0)+COUNTIF($A:$A,D1)),INDEX(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0)+COUNTIF($A:$A,$D2)-1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($D$2))),"")
```

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. And if there is an unknown amount of rows?

Comment: @OliverYasuna I've added the formula to the answer for that case

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA alternative:

```vb
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1335738/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Public Sub UnPivot()
       Dim ¡ As Long

  Const s_SourceColumns As String = "A:B"
  Const s_TargetColumn As String = "D"
  Const b_HasHeader As Boolean = True

  Dim lngSourceRows As Long
  lngSourceRows = ActiveSheet.Columns(s_SourceColumns).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + CLng(b_HasHeader)
  Dim varSource As Variant
  varSource = ActiveSheet.Columns(s_SourceColumns).Resize(RowSize:=lngSourceRows + 1).Offset(RowOffset:=-CLng(b_HasHeader)).Value2
  Dim idxNewCompany As Long: idxNewCompany = LBound(varSource, 1)
  Dim strNewCompany As String: strNewCompany = varSource(idxNewCompany, 1)
  Dim varUnPivotedData() As Variant
  ReDim varUnPivotedData(1 To lngSourceRows)
  varUnPivotedData(1) = strNewCompany
  Dim celNextTargetStart As Range
  Set celNextTargetStart = ActiveSheet.Columns(s_TargetColumn).Resize(RowSize:=1).Offset(RowOffset:=-CLng(b_HasHeader))
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For ¡ = LBound(varSource, 1) To UBound(varSource, 1) - 1
    varUnPivotedData(¡ - idxNewCompany + 2) = varSource(¡, 2)
    If varSource(¡ + 1, 1) <> strNewCompany Then
      ReDim Preserve varUnPivotedData(1 To ¡ - idxNewCompany + 2)
      celNextTargetStart.Resize(ColumnSize:=UBound(varUnPivotedData)).Value2 = varUnPivotedData
      Set celNextTargetStart = celNextTargetStart.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
      idxNewCompany = ¡ + 1
      strNewCompany = varSource(idxNewCompany, 1)
      ReDim varUnPivotedData(1 To lngSourceRows)
      varUnPivotedData(1) = strNewCompany
    End If
  Next ¡
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Just change the constants at the top of the code to suit your situation.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select A2:A11 and Name the Range **COMPANY**.
- Select B2:B11 and Name the Range **IDs**.
- Write this array formula in Cell C2 to *generate unique list of Companies*:

  ```
  {=INDEX($A$2:$A$11, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$11), 0))}
  ```

**N.B.** *Finish above written formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.*

- Write this array formula in Cell D2, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and **fill right then down.**

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(IDs,SMALL(IF(Company=$C2,ROW(IDs)-MIN(ROW(IDs))+1),COLUMNS($C$2:C2))),"")}
  ```

**Note,**

- *This formula will work smoothly, in case if there are variable number
  of IDs for each company.*
- *You get the list of Ids in Columns as shown in the Screen Shot.*

Comment: What is wrong with this Formula since it's working properly !!